# Why doesn't lithium form di-lithium crystals? (Calling Mr.Spock)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry

Hydrogen is in the first column of the periodic table.  At STP it is a di-atomic gas.  When cooled and/or under pressure it forms a crystalline solid of di-hydrogen molecules.  Calculations indicate that under high enough pressure it may form a monatomic basis metallic crystal, and scientists are actively looking to find evidence of this.  Results so far seem inconclusive.

However, Lithium is also a first column element.  But its solid is a monatomic basis metal and NOT a di-lithium crystal as we would expect based on hydrogen.  Why not?

Comment: Well [dilithium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilithium) does exist. It's a gas at room temperature.

Comment: indeed - but just as mysterious it is only like 1% of the gas, which is also very unlike hydrogen

Comment: I can't give you a reason but Hydrogen is a weird molecule. It shows similar properties to both the halogens(last column) and the Alkali Metals(first column). It's position in the periodic table has always been quite debatable.

Comment: Lithium on the other hand is a typical Alkali Metal and most of its properties are similar to others like Sodium etc.

Comment: indeed - so fluorine and chlorine are diatomic ... fluorine is one electron short of a full n=2 shell, but chlorine is similar to the "argon problem" I have asked about in another question

Comment: I strongly believe that you should ask this on [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah, but I am a physicist by training and I have a strong prior that simple quantum systems belong to physics ... can't the computer guys now solve dilithium and the lithium crystal?

Comment: Sorry sir. I am a high school student and have a **strong** prior that you should post it on both the stack exchanges.

Comment: Most cool!  I last took a chemistry course before your parents were born :-o   At that time I was told that simple molecules would be "physics" and not "chemistry" by the year 2000 ...  but it looks like chemistry stack exchange it is!

Comment: Please post a link here too as many would love to read the answer. Or you can start a bounty if you like.

Comment: et voila:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107423/why-doesnt-lithium-form-di-lithium-crystals-calling-mr-spock

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on chemistry stack exchange, I think the answer is this:
The n=1 s level of hydrogen is much much harder to ionize than the higher quantum number outer s states of the alkali metals.  After all, in a hydrogen atom n=1 is four times as tightly bound as n=2.  However, electron affinities are close to the same for all.  As a result, alkali metals easily lose their outer electron to "the swamp" and form a metal.  But hydrogen just won't let go, so it forms a diatomic molecule as a consolation prize.

Of the alkali metals, a few dilithium molecules will form in the gas phase, but fewer still for any of the heavier alkali metals.